# Copy values from one column in a pandas dataframe only when target field is blank in target dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have 2 dataframes of equal length. The source has one column, ML_PREDICTION that I want to copy to the target dataframe, which has some values already that I don't want to overwrite.

```
#Select only blank values in target dataframe
mask = br_df['RECOMMENDED_ACTION'] == ''

# Attempt 1 - Results: KeyError: "['Retain' 'Retain' '' ... '' '' 'Retain'] not in index" 
br_df.loc[br_df['RECOMMENDED_ACTION'][mask]] = ML_df['ML_PREDICTION'][mask]
br_df.loc['REASON_CODE'][mask] = 'ML01' 
br_df.loc['COMMENT'][mask] =  'Automated Prediction'

# Attempt 2 - Results: Overwrites all values in target dataframe
br_df['RECOMMENDED_ACTION'].where(mask, other=ML_df['ML_PREDICTION'], inplace=True)
br_df['REASON_CODE'].where(mask, other='ML01', inplace=True)
br_df['COMMENT'].where(mask, other='Automated Prediction', inplace=True)

# Attempt 3 - Results: Overwrites all values in target dataframe
br_df['RECOMMENDED_ACTION'] = [x for x in ML_df['ML_PREDICTION'] if [mask] ]
br_df['REASON_CODE']  = ['ML01' for x in ML_df['ML_PREDICTION'] if [mask]]
br_df['COMMENT'] = ['Automated Prediction' for x in ML_df['ML_PREDICTION'] if [mask]]

Attempt 4 - Results: Values in target (br_df) were unchanged
br_df.loc[br_df['RECOMMENDED_ACTION'].isnull(), 'REASON_CODE'] = 'ML01'
br_df.loc[br_df['RECOMMENDED_ACTION'].isnull(), 'COMMENT'] = 'Automated Prediction'
br_df.loc[br_df['RECOMMENDED_ACTION'].isnull(), 'RECOMMENDED_ACTION'] = ML_df['ML_PREDICTION']
```

## Attempt 5

@Dipanjan

```
`    # Before - br_df['REASON_CODE'].value_counts()
    BR03    10
    BR01     8
    Name: REASON_CODE, dtype: int64 

    #Attempt 5 
    br_df.loc['REASON_CODE'] = br_df['REASON_CODE'].fillna('ML01')
    br_df.loc['COMMENT'] = br_df['COMMENT'].fillna('Automated Prediction')
    br_df.loc['RECOMMENDED_ACTION'] = br_df['RECOMMENDED_ACTION'].fillna(ML_df['ML_PREDICTION'])

    # After -- print(br_df['REASON_CODE'].value_counts())
    BR03                    10
    BR01                     8
    ML01                     2
    Automated Prediction     1
    Name: REASON_CODE, dtype: int64

    #WTF? -- br_df[br_df['REASON_CODE'] == 'Automated Prediction']
    PERSON_STATUS   ...  RECOMMENDED_ACTION REASON_CODE COMMENT
    COMMENT NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN Automated Prediction    Automated Prediction    Automated Prediction
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you show your dataframe and your expected dataframe? Just an example for clarity.

Comment: @MohitMotwani 'code' br_df['RECOMMENDED_ACTION'] = 'Retain', '','Reject,'',Retain','','',...] ML_df['ML_PREDICTION']

Comment: @MohitMotwani 'code' br_df['RECOMMENDED_ACTION'] = ['Retain', '', 'Reject, '', 'Retain', '', '',...]   ML_df['ML_PREDICTION'] =  ['Retain', Retain', 'Reject', 'Retain', 'Reject', ...]  mask = [False, True, False, False, True, True,...]  After the code runs  br_df['RECOMMENDED_ACTION'] = ['Retain',  'Retain', 'Reject',  'Retain', 'Reject' ,...]   So br_df['RECOMMENDED_ACTION']  has some blanks and ML_df['ML_PREDICTION'] fills them in so that there are no null values at the end.

Answer (score 0):

use below options -

```
df.loc[df['A'].isnull(), 'A'] = df['B']
```

or

```
df['A'] = df['A'].fillna(df['B'])

import numpy as np
df_a = pd.DataFrame([0,1,np.nan])
df_b = pd.DataFrame([0,np.nan,2])
```

df_a

```
    0
0   0.0
1   1.0
2   NaN
```

df_b

```
    0
0   0.0
1   NaN
2   2.0

df_a[0] = df_a[0].fillna(df_b[0])
```

final_output-
df_a

```
    0
0   0.0
1   1.0
2   2.0
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response - I translated you suggestion at attempt #4. Oddly, the target dataframe was unchanged. Perhaps I got it wrong?

Comment: df['A'] = df['A'].fillna(df['B']) - can you try with this one. Workes fine with me.

Comment: @Dipanjon - so fillna('') impacts everything, not just the column I'm working on, so that didn't work as expected. I'm still looking for a solution. Thanks for the suggestions - keep them coming!

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, this is the syntax that appears to solve my problem:

```
mask = mask[:len(br_df)] # create the boolean index
br_df = br_df[:len(mask)] # make sure they are the same length
br_df['RECOMMENDED_ACTION'].loc[mask] =  ML_df['ML_PREDICTION'].loc[mask]
br_df['REASON_CODE'].loc[mask] = 'ML01'
br_df['COMMENT'].loc[mask] = 'Automated Prediction'
```